# CSS not working as desired with interpolation in angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a use case where I want to show notifications for a user in my web-application. The number of the notifications to be shown will depend on how many inquiries the user has gotten. Therefore I'm trying to use interpolation to dynmaically show how many notifications a certain user have. My problem is, that my CSS styling only works if the number of notifications provided is static.

Here's an example of what it looks like, when using a static number(this is my desired result): [image of how i want my notifications to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcwzW.png)

This is achieved by following code:

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown" dropdown>

  <span class="notification has-badge" innerHTML="4" 
   *ngIf="newNotificationsAvailable" >  </span>

       <a dropdownToggle mdbWavesEffect type="button" class="nav-link 
        dropdown-toggle waves-light fa fa-user" *ngIf="isLoggedIn" 
        mdbWavesEffect>

            Profile<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

And the CSS:

```
.notification[innerHTML]:after {
    position:absolute;
    right:86%;
    top:0%;
    content: attr(innerHTML);
    font-size:60%;
    padding:.6em;
    border-radius:999px;
    line-height:.75em;
    color: white;
    background:rgba(255,0,0,.85);
    text-align:center;
    min-width:2em;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

When i then try to add interpolation to make the number of notifications show more dynamically, I get this result: [Result when adding interpolation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LaX0.png)

The only difference is in my html:

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown" dropdown>

  <span class="notification has-badge" innerHTML="{{testvar}}" 
   *ngIf="newNotificationsAvailable" >  </span>

       <a dropdownToggle mdbWavesEffect type="button" class="nav-link 
        dropdown-toggle waves-light fa fa-user" *ngIf="isLoggedIn" 
        mdbWavesEffect>

            Profile<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Where the only difference is that my innerHTML = {{testvar}} instead of 4.

My corrosponding .ts file i just have the testvar set to 5:

```
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

     public testvar = 5;


     //...plus a bunch of irrelevant code.
   }
```

Can anyone help me understand why my css is responding different to non-static values?

Comment: It looks like you want `ng-bind-html="testvar"` instead of that innerHTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second example effectively results in `<span class="notification has-badge" ></span>`.

`innerHTML="{{testvar}}"` causes Angular to bind the value of `testvar` to the property `innerHtml`. It thereby effectively removes the attribute from the HTML, because the property has no corresponding attribute. So when the browser tries to render `content: attr(innerHTML);` there simply is no such attribute.

Instead of `innerHTML` you can use the `title` attribute, that would work. Or you include the value in your HTML.

Comment: Thank you! Very good explanation and worked perfectly with the title attribute :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<span class="notification has-badge"
      *ngIf=newNotificationsAvailable && testvar">
  {{testvar}}
</span>
```

Comment: I think you added two *ngIfs by mistake :-)

Comment: By mistake.. Yes :-D